# Wix - Run custom action when modifying existing install

Tags: wix, sequence, conditional-statements, custom-action

I'm trying to run a custom action on first install and any subsequent modification(adding/removing features of the installed product).

Which condition should I check?
I'm using the following but it doesn't work.

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action='SetParams' After='InstallFinalize'>NOT Installed OR WixUI_InstallMode = "Change"</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Thanks

Comment: to run a custom action on first install and any subsequent modification(adding/removing features of the installed product): Is this means that the custom action should run every time??

Comment: The custom action shouldn't run on uninstall as it would throw an exception and break the uninstall process.

Comment: @vinay I've just realized that I've pasted the wrong custom action - the problematic one is called in the execute sequence. I've updated the original post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this condition:

```
REMOVE <> "ALL"
```

It's true for a first time install and any maintenance operation except uninstall.

Comment: This isn't quite true.  REMOVE is also set to ALL during major upgrades.